# Verify the proof of $1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, solution-verification

I  am trying prove $x_n=1+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n!}$ is Cauchy.

Here is what I tried:

Let $\epsilon>0$ and  $n>m$

follows that
$|x_n-x_m|=\bigg{|}\dfrac{1}{n!}+\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{(m+1)!}\bigg{|} < \dfrac{n-m}{(m+1)!}$

When $ m \to \infty$ follows $(n-m) \to 0$ and

$|x_n-x_m|<\dfrac{n-m}{(m+1)!}\to 0$

thus $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$

Can anyone verify my answer

Comment: For $\epsilon > 0$, what $N$ do you choose so that $$m,n\ge N \implies |x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$$

Comment: "When $ m \to \infty$ follows $(n-m) \to 0$" is not automatically true and wrecks the rest of your proof.  What happens to  $\frac{n-m}{(m+1)!}$ when $n=(m+2)!+m$ and $ m \to \infty$ ?

Comment: @Henry thank you  for pointing out it. Can you give some hint?

Comment: You might prefer to use $\dfrac{1}{(n+k)!}\le \dfrac1{n! n^k}$

Comment: @Henry thank you I will try

Answer (score 4):

For $x_n=1+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!}+..+\dfrac{1}{n!}$ in place/additionally  of Henry's comment, let me suggest
$$x_{m+n}-x_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\cdots +\frac{1}{(n+m)!}\lt\\ \lt \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2} +  \cdots\right)=\\
=\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \frac{n+2}{(n+1)}\lt \frac{1}{n!\cdot n}$$